# Note or textbook about algebraic k-theory

Tags: book-recommendation, algebraic-k-theory

I'm reading the Weibel's K-book. It's difficult for me. I have read some $K_0$ with the hlep of Bass' book. But Bass' book is so old. So, are there any more detailed books or notes to recommend.

I appreciate any advice, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some useful list:

In any field (and any level!), Milnor is a nice choice:

1. *Milnor, John W.*, [**Introduction to algebraic K-theory**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1515/9781400881796), Annals of Mathematics Studies. No. 72. Princeton, N. J.: Princeton University Press and University of Tokyo Press. XIII, 184 p. $ 6.25 (1971). [ZBL0237.18005](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0237.18005).

and some other Books:

2. *Rosenberg, Jonathan*, Algebraic K-theory and its applications, Graduate Texts in Mathematics. 147. New York, NY: Springer-Verlag. x, 392 p. (1994). [ZBL0801.19001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0801.19001).
3. *Inassaridze, Hvedri*, Algebraic (K)-theory, Mathematics and its Applications (Dordrecht). 311. Dordrecht: Kluwer Academic Publishers. 438 p. ; (1995). [ZBL0836.19001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0836.19001).
4. *Dundas, Bjørn Ian; Goodwillie, Thomas G.; McCarthy, Randy*, [**The local structure of algebraic K-theory**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4471-4393-2), Algebra and Applications 18. London: Springer (ISBN 978-1-4471-4392-5/hbk; 978-1-4471-4393-2/ebook). xv, 435 p. (2013). [ZBL1272.55002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1272.55002).
5. *Lluis-Puebla, Emilio; Loday, Jean-Louis; Gillet, Henri; Soulé, Christophe; Snaith, Victor*, [**Higher algebraic (K)-theory: an overview**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BFb0088876), Lecture Notes in Mathematics. 1491. Berlin etc.: Springer-Verlag. ix, 164 p. (1992). [ZBL0746.19001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0746.19001).